# Is making /var/log directory read only on debian linux safe?

Tags: permissions, logs

I am installing a really small server which got a 512mb CF cars as HD.
Not only I haven't plenty of space, but I would like to minimize the writes to disk.

I would like to completely clear the /var/log directory and to make it read only (write protected).

Will the system hang if I do so?

Comment: `/var/log` being read only doesn't make much sense. You'd probably be better off rotating regularly and compressing the old log files.

Comment: Or adjusting your settings on the log daemon so it only logs emergency and critical level logs.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of making it  read only, I would create `/var/log` as tempfs. and regularily prune. Of course that only works if you have enough spare RAM available.

You can do the same for other possible non-essential directories like `/var/tmp`

Entries in my `/etc/fstab` (now commented out):

```
tmpfs   /var/tmp   tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777,size=128M   0  0
tmpfs   /var/log   tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=0755,size=128M   0  0
```

Comment: One problem with this would be using the log files to diagnose a system hang.

Comment: You probably want to include a `size=` parameter to control for the RAM usage issue you mentioned.

Comment: @JoelDavis Size limitation would be appropriate, I added that parameter (on my machine this was not a problem). I reckoned that if the OP was willing to make /var/log read-only, that throwing away logs on reboot would not be an issue.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Debian FHS (Filesystem Hierarchy Standard),](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/fhs/fhs-2.3.html#VARLOGLOGFILESANDDIRECTORIES) /var/log must be writable. Upon boot up, the system itself must be able to write to a log in that directory. You can make /usr read-only, but /var should be mounted writeable.

To answer the question asked in your write-up, yes the system will hang on start up. The kernel will attempt to write to dmesg, and will hang when it cannot.

Comment: The kernel won't "hang" when it cannot write to `/var/log/`, otherwise your system would not be able to boot because `/var/log/` is not mounted at boot. It is possible that some programs do not start, crash or do not function properly.

Comment: FHS is not by Deban; they only cite it. It is a standard which is relevant for all kind of Unixes and alike systems.

Answer (score 4):

If you are planning on making it read-only, then it is as good as worthless. You should control how and what you log.

If you are running short on space, you might want to have a separate reasonably-sized /var partition and choose a file system that can handle lots of small files, such as ReiserFS or something.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in my comment, a writable `/var/log` is kind of important but there are things you can do to ensure that as little gets saved as possible. For example, you can configure `logrotate` to rotate the log files based on their size, compressing the old ones. You can also configure `syslog` to only write `CRIT` and above to the logs (the rest are discarded)

`logrotate` example:

```
   compress

   /var/log/messages {
       rotate 5
       size 100k
       postrotate
           /usr/bin/killall -HUP syslogd
       endscript
   }
```

(You would need to configure `logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf` to be ran in a cronjob as well).

`rsyslog.conf` example:

```
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)

$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

*.crit                                                  /var/log/messages
*.emerg                                                 *
```

This is probably the best middle ground as next to nothing gets logged but you're still notified of critical events. You may also think about configuring remote syslog to a server with bigger storage if log retention is important.